# Поиск в RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

Вопрос довольно частый, приложение загружает данные с сервера, хотелось бы реализовать поиск в `RecyclerView`. Смотрел много примеров но не смог разобраться((

Очень прошу помочь примером в моем вопросе.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    List<JsonData> routeList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        routeList = new ArrayList<>(); 

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        DataAdapter adapter = new DataAdapter(routeList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        logisticAPI lAPI = logisticAPI.retrofit.create(logisticAPI.class);

        String login = "log";
        String password = "pass";
        String base = login +","+ password;

        String authHeader = Base64.encodeToString(base.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

        final Call<List<JsonData>> call = lAPI.getData(authHeader);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<JsonData>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<JsonData>> call, Response<List<JsonData>> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    routeList.addAll(response.body());
                    mRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    // Обрабатываем ошибку
                    ResponseBody errorBody = response.errorBody();
                    try {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, errorBody.string(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<JsonData>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("mData",t.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Что-то пошло не так",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Сам Адаптер

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<JsonData> routeList;
    private Context mContext;

    public DataAdapter(List<JsonData> routeList) {
        this.routeList = routeList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        mContext = parent.getContext();
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DataAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final JsonData routeTask = routeList.get(position);

        holder.name.setText(Html.fromHtml(routeTask.getCompany().getName()));
        holder.phoneNumber.setText(routeTask.phoneNumber());         
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (routeList == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return routeList.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView name, phoneNumber;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);                
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameText);
            phoneNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.phoneNumberText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: поиск надо делать не по recyclerview, а по списку получаемому с сервера. Фильтровать этот список и отображать на recyclerview

Comment: Как бы там ни было, хотелось бы знать как это реализовать?

Comment: Поиск по каким признакам? по словам? по определенным критериям?

Comment: В вашем примере у вас есть лист объектов JsonData в onResponse. Просто пройдитесь циклом по этом листу и найдите нужные значение. А в Adapter передавайте уже ваш новый лист с новыми значениями

Answer (score 1):

необходимо реализовать метод **getFilter()** в твоем адаптере.

Пример реализации:

```
    public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    //Твой исходный лист с данными
    private List<JsonData> routeList = new ArrayList<>();
    //Твой фильтрованный лист
    private List<JsonData> filterList = new ArrayList<>();

public DataAdapter() {    
}

  public void addData(List<JsonData> data){
        this.routeList.clear();
        this.filterList.clear();
        this.routeList.addAll(data);
        this.filterList.addAll(data);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
  }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return filterList.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DataAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
 //Берем данные из фильтрованного листа   
 final JsonData routeTask = filterList.get(position);

    holder.name.setText(Html.fromHtml(routeTask.getCompany().getName()));
    holder.phoneNumber.setText(routeTask.phoneNumber());         
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            String charString = charSequence.toString();
            if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                filterList = routeList;
            } else {
                List<JsonData> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (JsonData row : routeList) {
                    //тут прописываешь условие по которому ты отбираешь данные
                    if (/* Какое нибудь условие */){
                        filteredList.add(row);
                    }
                }

                //присваиваем нашему листу, который отвечает за фильтр, рузельтат
                filterList = filteredList;
            }

            //Отправляем результат фильтрации
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = filterList;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            filterList = (ArrayList<JsonData>) filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            //говорим адаптеру что данные изменились
        }
    };
}

  class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView name, phoneNumber;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);                
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameText);
            phoneNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.phoneNumberText);
        }
    }
}
```

В твоем активити ты получаешь и сеттишь данные в адаптер. Пример **Actvity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private DataAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        adapter = new DataAdapter();
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

      logisticAPI lAPI = logisticAPI.retrofit.create(logisticAPI.class);

        String login = "log";
        String password = "pass";
        String base = login +","+ password;

        String authHeader = Base64.encodeToString(base.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

        final Call<List<JsonData>> call = lAPI.getData(authHeader);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<JsonData>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<JsonData>> call, Response<List<JsonData>> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    adapter.addData(response.body());
                } else {
                    // Обрабатываем ошибку
                    ResponseBody errorBody = response.errorBody();
                    try {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, errorBody.string(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<JsonData>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("mData",t.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Что-то пошло не так",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Затем, после того как ты получил данные, ты можешь выполнять поиск по листу, следующим образом:

```
adapter.getFilter().filter(/* Необходимые для поиска слова */)
```

Например, у тебя есть **EditText** при изменение текста которого, вызывается код фильтра - список фильтруется.

Comment: Возвращает пустой список, поставил логирование данных в `public void onBindViewHolder` все данные поступают, но не отображаются. При поиске выдает ошибку `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.widget.Filter example.ru.logapp.adapter.DataAdapter.getFilter()' on a null object reference`

Comment: не хватало метода getItemCount() в адаптере, я исправил ответ. По поводу ошибки, вероятнее всего вы не проинициализировали переменную адаптера в активности, на котором вызываете фильтр.

Comment: Да, я это сразу заметил и сам добавил. Но боюсь что проблема в другом

Comment: по прежнему ничего не отображает ?

Comment: Да! Нет никаких данных((

Comment: сейчас я подрефакторю ответ

Comment: я подрефакторил чуть чуть, по идее сейчас должно

Comment: Теперь вообще целая куча ошибок((, вы сами не пробовали компилировать?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (response.isSuccessful()){
                ArrayList<JsonData> newList = new Arraylist();
                newList.addAll(response.body());

                for(int i=0; i<newList.size(); i++){
                 //тут поставьте по какому значению хотите отфильтровать. И в класс JsonData не забудьте сделать get метод
                    if(newList.get(i).getId().equals("My filter Id"){ 
                     routeList.add(newList.get(i));
                    }
                }
                mRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                // Обрабатываем ошибку
                ResponseBody errorBody = response.errorBody();
                try {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, errorBody.string(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```